# C++ SQLite importing entire CSV file in C Interface

Tags: c++, performance, sqlite, visual-c++

Is there a way to Import an entire CSV file into SQLite through the C Interface?

I'm aware of the commandline import that looks like this,

```
   sqlite> .mode csv <table>
   sqlite> .import <filename> <table>
```

but I need to be able to do this in my program.

I should also note that I have successfully created a CSV reader in C++ that reads in a CSV file and inserts its content to a table line by line.

This gets the job done but with a CSV containing 730k lines this method takes ~20 minutes to load which is WAY too long. (This is going to be around average size of the stuff being processed)

(Machine: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU E8500 @ 3.16GHz 3.17GHz, 4.0 GB Ram, Windows 7 64 bit, Visual studios 2010)

This is unacceptable for my project so I need a faster way, something taking around 2-3 minutes.

Is there a way to reference the file's memory location so Import isn't necessary? If so is access of the information slow?

Can SQLite take the CSV file as binary data? Would this make importing the file any faster?

Ideas?

Note: I'm using the ":memory:" option with the C Interface to load the DB in memory to increase speed (I hope).

### EDIT

After doing some more optimizing I found [this](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q19). It explains how you can group insert statements into 1 transaction by writing.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
INSERT into TABLE VALUES(...);
...Million more INSERT statements
INSERT into TABLE VALUES(...);
COMMIT;
```

This created a **HUGE** improvement in performance.

**Useful Related Side Note**

Also if you're looking to a create table from a query's results or Insert query results into a table try [this](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html) for creating tables or [this](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) for inserting results into a table.

The insert link might not be obvious for inserting into a table. The query to do that looks like this.

```
INSERT INTO [TABLE] [QUERY]
```

where `[TABLE]` is the table you want the results of `[QUERY]` the query you're running to go into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have successfully created a CSV reader in C++ that reads in a CSV file and inserts its content to a table line by line...  takes ~20 minutes to load

Put all your inserts into a single transaction - or at least batch up 100 or 1000 rows per transaction - and I would expect your program to run much faster.

Comment: This Improved time by about a minute. I assume there is another bottle neck in my code somewhere. :/ Do you have any comments about the file pointer or binary data ideas?

Comment: Let's see your loop. Something sounds off; it shouldn't take that long.  (I don't know about the binary data option etc)

Comment: It had to do with the way I was packaging the data and handing it to an Insert function(For Maintainability). I put all the logic into the parsing loop and I'm at ~12 min which is much better. This still seems slow but I'm sure it's me. I'll keep looking for things that would add to the O-Notation and kill them. Thanks!

Comment: After some testing and removing of that huge bottle neck. Your answer did shave 2-5 minutes off the time. By buffering all the insert statements and submitting them when I reach the end of the file I'm running at ~9.5 minutes which is usable. There's still room for improvement somewhere but your answer definitely helped a lot. Thanks.